# What is the file format for xml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For format.js I needed create.js.erb file in line_items view

```
format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
```

For format.xml should I use create.xml.erb ?

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                     :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to create `create.xml.erb`. By doing this

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                     :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

you are calling `to_xml` on `@line_item` and returning it as response